# Differentiability of f(z) using Cauchy-Riemann and First Principles

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, derivatives, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

If $f(z)=z|z-1|^2$ where $z=x+iy$. I need to show where it is differentiable, and then from first principles find its derivative at each point.

I have started by saying $f=(x+iy)((x-1)^2+y^2)$

After doing Cauchy-Riemann, I have the following

$U_x=3x^2 -2x^2+x+xy^2\\ 
V_x = 2xy-2y\\
U_y= 2xy  \\
V_y= x^2-2x+1+3y^2$

I am really stuck as to what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
U'_x = V'_y \\
U'_y = -V'_x 
\end{cases}
$$

Your $U'_x$ seems wrong though. I get
$$
\begin{cases}
U'_x = 3x^2 -4x + y^2 +1 \\
U'_y = 2xy \\
V'_x = 2xy - 2y \\
V'_y = x^2-2x+1 + 3y^2
\end{cases}
$$
Looking at $U'_y = -V'_x$ we get $2xy = -2xy+2y$, i.e. $4xy-2y = 0$ or $2y(2x-1) = 0$. Hence, $y=0$ or $x=1/2$.

If $y=0$, $U'_x = V'_y$ reduces to
$$
3x^2-4x + 1 = x^2-2x+1 \quad\iff\quad 2x(x-1) = 0
$$
i.e. $x=0$ or $x=1$.

On the other hand, if $x=1/2$ then
$$
\frac34 - 2 + y^2 + 1= \frac14 - 1 + 1 + 3y^2
$$
which has no real solutions.

Since $U$ and $V$ are $C^1$, we see that your function is complex differentiable at $z=0$ and  $z=1$ and no other points.

If you know the formalism of Wirtinger derivatives, the above computation will be a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you so much, i see you have solved for x and y, but how do you get z from this?

Comment: Also how do i get the derivatives at the points from first principles?

Comment: $z=x+iy$. $f' = U'_x+iV'_x$ for example (where $f'$ exists)

Comment: Apologies but i have no idea where you got z from. you said $y=0$ and $x=0$ or $1$. How do you get z?

Comment: Also, what is C^1